# how to get escape hot key to work in tiny

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

So i am using hotkeys to fire off a function to save content that has been entered in the RTE. that works fine but i am also trying to use the "Esc" hotkey to cancel editing. the "Esc" hotkey does not seem to work. here is my code

```
<Editor
  value={co.description}
  onEditorChange={(content) => {
    this.handleEditorInputChange(content, 'description');
  }}
  init={{
    height: 300,
    menubar: false,
    plugins: ['lists'],
    toolbar: 'bullist numlist | bold italic underline',
    browser_spellcheck: true,
    setup: (editor) => {
      editor.addShortcut(
        editor.shortcuts.add(
          'ctrl+s',
          '',
          function () {
            this.saveCo(this.context.co);
          },
          this,
        ),
        editor.shortcuts.add(
          'Esc',
          '',
          function () {
            this.cancelEdit();
          },
          this,
        ),
      );
    },
  }}
/>
```

any ideas?

Comment: I did find this editor.on('keydown', (e) => {if(e.keyCode === 27) { this.cancelEdit() }}, this) and it seems to work besides getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStart' of null